# netstat says connection in SYN_SENT but tcpdump captures no data

Tags: tcpdump, netstat

I'm debugging a ldap problem after ldap client machine upgraded to ubuntu 18.04. Trying to figure out where the problem is, and I noticed the outbound connection is in SYN_SENT, but when I use tcpdump to capture the problem, both server and client machine's tcpdump has no data about that specific connection, just like it stuck in the kernel's tcp stack. Is there any possible problem that caused this symptom?

Some background:

LDAP server ubuntu 16.04.5, LDAP client 18.04.1

ldap client program: `pam_ldap` and `systemd-logind`(which uses `nss-ldap`)

`pam_ldap` can connect to ldap server and bind without problem and tcpdump captures the packet.

`systemd-logind` always complain about `do_start_tls failed: stat=-1`, `netstat` shows `SYN_SENT` and tcpdump captures no outbound packet.

Same configuration on 16.04 works without any problem.

Comment: You should include the full line from the `netstat` output in your question. It may contain other relevant information.

Comment: netstat output only contains successful connection (made by pam_ldap) and SYN_SENT connection (made by system_logind). Confirmed with strace.

Comment: It's the firewall.  It's *always* the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Disable Apparmor completely and this problem solved. It seems that Appamor blocked systemd-logind outbound connection.